# Locking in ‘set +e’ in a Bash shell

Tags: bash

Is there a way to lock in ‘set +e’ in a Bash shell in a way where sourced scripts calling ‘set -e’ can’t override?

Also would need to be possible for sub shells to still be able to still ‘set -e’.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to show us some more context on how this _sourced_ scripts are called and how the sub-shells are used in your script

Comment: This sounds like a poor idea to me.  Scripts that explicitly `set -e` very likely do so because they *depend* on it for proper operation under some circumstances.  Some scripts may depend on that even without explicitly running `set`, for that matter.

Comment: I suspect this is an X-Y problem.  What are you actually trying to accomplish via `set +e`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger agreed that this is generally considered bad practice to interrupt intended workflow of a script. Really boils down to blocking `errexit` on scripts that are being sourced into a shell that is not meant to ever be exited (via sourced script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite the builtin `set` command temporarily with a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

set() { [[ "$1" != "-e" ]] && command set "${@}"; }
# source your script here
unset set # if you want to use set -e again
```

Comment: oh interesting, and would this ‘set’ function declared within the shell persist to the environment of a (non-sourced) bash script call?

Comment: If you do not call `unset set`, you can use the function several times in your script. But it is not bulletproof, because it can be bypassed in your sourced file with `set -x -e`, for example.

Comment: Of course, a sourced script that wants to overcome such a countermeasure can easily do so by the same mechanism the function itself uses: the `command` command.  It could also itself `unset` the function.

Comment: @Cyrus agreed that the solution has its drawbacks, but you steered me in the right direction, so thanks! This is what I ultimately went with:


`set() { command set "${@}"; setres=$? ; if [[ -o errexit ]] ; then set +e && echo "A process just attempted to 'set -e'" && false ; else return $setres ; fi }`